# SQL Select count of items from a child table with a where clause

Tags: sql, subquery, outer-join

SQL Query :

```
select c.cid, la.lid, b.bid, b.type 
from c c 
  left join la la on c.cid = la.cid
  left join b b on la.lid = b.lid
where b.type = 'Primary';
```

There are three tables c -> la -> b

I need the total count of 'b' for any given 'la' but I need to have " b.type = 'Primary' " in the where clause for other purposes.

b.type has two types - Primary and Secondary but I want a count of total number of 'b' (Primary and Secondary) Can somebody give any hints ? It would be a good learning for me. Thanks.

[sample data and desired o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lAXB.png)

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but: the condition `where b.type = 'Primary'` turns both your outer joins back into inner joins.

Comment: It would be better if you could provide us a simple sample of data as well as your expected result.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to have the where clause?

Comment: yes, its required.

Comment: Why you have table c in the query?

Comment: c(parent ) -> la(child) -> b(grand child)

Comment: What your request is missing: 1) The sample data should be pasted as text here. 2) You forgot to tell us which DBMS you are using. Tag your request accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  c.cid, 
  la.lid, 
  b.bid, 
  b.type,
  d.cbdi
FROM c c 
LEFT JOIN la la ON c.cid = la.lid
LEFT JOIN b b ON la.lid2 = b.lid2
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
              la.lid,
              COUNT(b.bid) AS cbid
            FROM la la 
            LEFT JOIN b b ON la.lid2 = b.lid2
            GROUP BY la.lid
          ) d ON la.lid = d.lid
WHERE
  b.type = 'Primary';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have row having `secondary` in desired output as per your attached screenshot because of clause `where b.type = 'Primary'`. Please check again, looks like your requirement is not clear.

Comment: Yes :) I am sure about the requirement. I am here to see if its possible or not !

Comment: Oh ok but I believe it is not possible by having the where clause `b.type = 'Primary'`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to show all rows unaggregated but show an aggregation (the b count) along. This is done with a window function, `COUNT OVER` in your case.

```
select c.cid, la.lid, b.bid, b.type, count(*) over (partition by la.lid) as number_of_b
from la
join c on c.cid = la.cid
join b on b.lid = la.lid
order by c.cid, la.lid, b.bid;
```

If you want to restrict this to `la` that have at least one primary `b`, extend this query accordingly:

```
select cid, lid, bid, type, number_of_b
from
(
  select
    c.cid, la.lid, b.bid, b.type,
    count(*) over (partition by la.lid) as number_of_b,
    max(case when b.type = 'Primary' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by la.lid)
      as has_primary_b
  from la
  join c on c.cid = la.cid
  join b on b.lid = la.lid
  order by c.cid, la.lid, b.bid
)
where has_primary_b = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to join table b twice on for selecting only the Primary records and one to count all. Something like:

```
select c.cid, la.lid, count(bt.id) 
from c c 
  join la la on c.cid = la.cid
  join b b on la.lid = b.lid
  join b bt on la.lid = bt.lid 
where b.type = 'Primary'
group by c.cid, la.lid;
```

Comment: Your query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause. Then, the sample data result (only a linked image unfortunately) does contain secondary b rows, so `where b.type = 'Primary'` doesn't seem appropriate. Then, `where b.type = 'Primary'` turns the outer join into an inner join, so either don't outer join or put the condition in the `ON` clause where it belongs.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: you are right, I edited my answer. Thanks.